# Half transparent color on a solid background of the same color how to make it contrast to see like in real life

Tags: inkscape

Working in Inkscape I have an object that is somewhat transparent. I wanted to put this object on a background of a solid color but the background color is the same too.

So after giving some thought to this question I'm asking what can I do to contrast the object to make it look like a half transparent, like a red balloon or red glass on a red background.

My idea was to make the background somewhat transparent and put white in it, so now I have this somewhat transparent red background with white in the middle and on the outer part of the background gradient.

But then I thought that I really do need a solid color cause even if this background like a spotlight white in the middle red going out back to white at the end cause in real life something has to be behind it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use a **tint** of the color rather than transparency.

[image]

This may mean you need to alter your objects. If the top object extends past the background object, the tint will still show, transparency may not.

[image]

Beyond this, I'm afraid an image in the question, as an example, may be needed to assist further.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I though about adding a background shadow to the transparent image i forgot how to do it with it just showing on the outer edge of the object in question.